# Replace single \ with double \\

Tags: regex, batch-file

I have batch file in which a path is passed as the first parameter.

```
set WSPACE=%1
```

where `%1` is a path (C:\somepath\workspace).

How do I manipulate `WSPACE` or `%1` before it is assigned to `WSPACE` so that the `\` will be changed to double `\\` so that paths look like
"C:\\somepath\\workspace"?

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "mydir=C:\somepath\workspace"
SET "awkward=\\2\\\3\\\\4\\\\\5\"

SET "s2=%sourcedir:\=\\%"
SET "d2=%destdir:\=\\%"
SET "m2=%mydir:\=\\%"
SET "a2=%awkward:\=\\%"

echo sourcedir=%sourcedir%==%s2%==
echo destdir=%destdir%==%d2%==
echo mydir=%mydir%==%m2%==
echo awkward=%awkward%==%a2%==

GOTO :EOF
```

here's a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

The regex to replace a single backslash with a double backslash would be:

```
s/\\/\\\\/g  (if you were running it in vi, for example.)
```

Not 100% sure if this is what you are asking though.

Answer (score 0):

So all I had to do was:

```
SET WSPACE=%1
SET "WSPACE=%WSPACE:\=\\%"
```

When I echo `%WSPACE%` it gives me the path I passed in but with double slashes

problem solved, thanks

Comment: Yes, as I demonstrated with four different strings, I believe - but you need `%var:\=\\%` - two backslashes after the `=`, not one...